# ComboBox items with multiple values per item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having trouble finding a good solution to this problem and was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with this.

```
private void frmModifyLeaderID_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        loadEmployees();
}

private void loadEmployees()
{
        dsEmployeesemp = new dsEmployees();
        cbEmployees.DataSource = emp.getEmployees();
        cbEmployees.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbEmployees.ValueMember = "id";
}

private void cbEmployees_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (cbEmployees.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                tbCurrentTeamLeaderID.Text = cbEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
}
```

This code works properly, but now I am running into an issue with a new requirement. When a user selects an item (by employee name) in the `ComboBox` (cbEmployees), I now need access to both the "id" column as well as another column in the DataSource `emp.getEmployees()` called "LeaderID".

At first I was going to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178057/add-items-to-combobox-with-multiple-values-c-sharp) solution also found on stackoverflow, but as I am using a `DataTable` as the `ComboBox`'s `DataSource` and using that `DataTable`'s column names as identifiers. I am unsure how to go forward with this.

I was thinking of using an iterative loop to go through the DataTable and create objects with both the "id" and "LeaderID" as the object's properties then store that object in the `cbEmployees.ValueMember`, but I can not get this to work.

If anyone knows a better solution it would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When data source is data table, items are of type of [`DataRowView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: One alternative solution: use the `Tag` property of the combobox, store the `LeaderID` in it. You would sync that with the selected item. Or as @RezaAghaei has already mentioned, you have a `DataRowView` with everything you already need. There are more than a few ways to accomplish this, if you update your post in the direction you want to go and it's not working we would be glad to help.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am now looking into the `Tag` property as you mentioned. It seems like a good option to use for extra information on a control. I will update you guys if these alternatives work or edit the post with further direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.

After looking at the comments posted to my question, Reza let me know that the items are of type [`DataRowView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). This made me realize that even though I set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of each row, the rest of the data in the `DataTable` was still accessible in each row.

With this realization, I changed my `cbEmployees_SelectedValueChanged` method to this:

```
var selectedEmp = (DataRowView)cbEmployees.SelectedItem;
tbCurrentTeamLeaderID.Text = selectedEmp["LeaderID"].ToString();
```

And with this, it now properly accesses and sets the value taken from the `LeaderID` column of the `DataTable`.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Only when you assign `cbEmployees.DataSource = emp.getEmployees();
        cbEmployees.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cbEmployees.ValueMember = "id";`, assign `DataSource` last